# Pandas get index and column from a cell in vectorized approach

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have been playing with Pandas for a while, so I am not sure this is actually feasible straight away, let me expose my problem:

I have an array such as:

```
0    |1|2|3|
1    |6|4|3|
2      |6|1|
dtype: object
```

Then I have a Data Frame I generated to do one hot encoding of such array:

```
    [[False False False False False]
 [False False  False  False  False]
 [ False  False  False  False False]]
```

Each row corresponds to the array row and columns are the different values from each array element, separated by | .

At this point I want to assign a True/False value to each cell depending of its index and column.
The value of the cell(R,C) will be true if the column C is contained in the array element A[R]

e.g.
cell(0,1) = True

Wanted to do this ina. vectorized approach, not sure I can do that just creating an initially empty dataframe, I may need to encode the index and column in the cell value?

I was using get dummies, but taking a look to the internals I see an iteration over the tags, just wondering if that was replaceable (I also had to customise it a little as the type was applied later on, causing a huge memory output temporarily)

Get Dummies

```
def str_get_boolean_dummies(arr, sep='|'):
arr = arr.fillna('')
try:
    arr = sep + arr + sep
except TypeError:
    arr = sep + arr.astype(str) + sep

tags = set()
for ts in arr.str.split(sep):
    tags.update(ts)
tags = sorted(tags - set([""]))

dummies = pd.np.empty((len(arr), len(tags)), dtype=pd.np.bool)

for i, t in enumerate(tags):
    pat = sep + t + sep
    dummies[:, i] = map_infer(arr.values, lambda x: pat in x)
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing arrays and dataframes. Also could you please post a sample of the output?

Comment: gmds answer got the point, I basically want to have the best possible get dummies

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `str.get_dummies`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['|1|2|3|'], ['|6|4|3|'], ['|6|1|']], columns=['text'])

print(df['text'].str.get_dummies().astype(bool))
```

Output:

```
       1      2      3      4      6
0   True   True   True  False  False
1  False  False   True   True   True
2   True  False  False  False   True
```

Comment: Just refined my question explaining why I was trying to improve from get_dummies.
A fair answer may be that is just not possible/worth the effort :)